# GET vs POST to send some parameters in rest

Tags: java, rest, post, get, jersey-2.0

I need to expose a rest api which needs 4 parameters, as of now. I have two options:

```
1) GET request with 4 query params  
2) POST request with an Object passed that encapsulates 4 parameters.
```

If i use `case 1)`, then what if in future, more parameters need to be sent thereby making URL lengthy as query parameters will be increased. If i use `case 2)`, then rest guideline will be violated as POST only meant to create/update.

Please let me know what is best approach in this case.

Comment: why query parameters and not say path parameters? Basically you are violating get/post just by comparing parameter count and without understanding the semantics of it.

Comment: the parameters i need to pass are actually meant for filtering, that's why query param instead of path para,

Comment: What is the resource? Check that you are not trying to implement RPC over REST.

Comment: I don't have too much experience with REST, but I think that your number is like a threshold. If there would have been 3, I would have said GET. If there would have been 5, I would have said POST. 

I believe that it's important if you already have a long path. For example, if the base URL is `http://localhost:<port>/<module>/<category>/<pathFromclass>/<pathFromMethod>`, then 4 parameters make it too long. In this case, use POST.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to pass long parameters, or binary ones, you'd normally use HTTP POST requests, and include the parameters in the POST body.

As a rule, GET requests should be for read-only queries; they should not change the state of the server and its data. For creation, updating, and deleting data, use POST requests. (POST can also be used for read-only queries when complex parameters are required.)

Reference: http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/more-complex-rest-requests.html

Also, you can refer here: [What is the best way to design a HTTP request when somewhat complex parameters are needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266596/what-is-the-best-way-to-design-a-http-request-when-somewhat-complex-parameters-a)

Comment: I actually don't understand what do you mean by complex parameters..does it refer number of parameters to be sent?

Comment: @Anand : Have you gone through second link that i have posted above, contains complex characters.

Comment: @Anand : For your information : Maximum length of HTTP GET request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Answer (score -1):

Filtering params can also be sent as header params in a get request as well.

Besides if necessary sending more request params doesn't harm.